# Convert a String to a specific picture, then displaying it as an icon in Jswing

Tags: java, swing, imageicon

I am trying to create a Blackjack game in Jswing. I have made some code that creates a deck of cards and then randomizes them. I then add a .png to the end of the Card String so that it can be displayed as an image.
My problem is with trying to convert the String (which the Array gives) to a image.
I have tried doing (Array[pos]+".png") and the setting the icon to the aforementioned String.
But this only displays a blank image.

What does this not work?

```
        int pos = 0;
    String faces[] = {"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "jack", "queen", "king", "ace"};
    String suits[] = {"hearts", "diamonds", "clubs", "spades"};

    String[] Array = new String[52];
    for (int j = 0; j < Array.length; j++) {
        Array[j] = faces[j % 13] + "_of_" + suits[j / 13];
    }

    List<String> StringList = Arrays.asList(Array);

    Collections.shuffle(StringList);

    StringList.toArray(Array);

    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(Array[pos] + ".png");
    pCard1.setIcon(icon);
    info.setText(Array[pos] + ".png"); //=> Gives something like "jack_of_diamonds.png" which is the format for the name of the pictures.
```

Comment: I would first suggest using ImageIO.read to load the images (over ImageIcon), this will cause an error if the image can’t be loaded

Comment: Because `ImageIcon(String)` is looking for a file in the "current working directory", I would also use `System.getProperty("user.home")` to determine what that is and ensure your image files are in the same directory - this, how well, will raise issues in the long and you should probably learn about "embedded resources"

Comment: You need to load [resources](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/80-loading-files-as-resources-in-java-with-eclipse)
. You might also consider the possibility of using Unicode playing card characters

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I just realised what I did wrong. I cant type (2_of_clubs.png) but insted have to type (src/2_of_clubs.png) despite both being in the same folder.

Comment: No. *Don't* do that. See my first sentence above

Comment: @MadProgrammer `System.getProperty("user.dir")` returns the current working directory.

Comment: Never reference src in your code